# FFMPEG & JNI : How to decode from URL

Tags: android, ffmpeg, java-native-interface, mpeg2-ts

I'm trying to make an android application that uses the FFMPEG for decoding videos that are not supported by Android ( not on all the devices at least ): MPEG-TS & h264 Main Profile.
So, until now, I was able to use FFMPEG from JNI to decode some local video with the above specs, but my goal is to make the FFMPEG decode data from a streaming URL (`http://127.0.0.1:1666/`) on which I will send buffers from an android service (for certain reasons)

So, basically, I have two questions :

- how I will be able to do the decoding from a streaming URL as I couldn't find any good example ?
- when decoding my local MPEG-TS video, I've noticed that the playback speed is quite slow, and it happen that the video freezes for a while, even the Dolphin Player (based on FFMPEG) has the same behavior, and I don't know if is there some solution for this. Any suggestion ?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can take this as an example you can follow

```
iobuffer                  = (unsigned char*) av_malloc(bufferSize);               
pFormatCtx                = avformat_alloc_context();   
pFormatCtx->pb            = avio_alloc_context(iobuffer, bufferSize, 0,receiver,    IORead, NULL, );
```

err = avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, "", NULL, NULL);

where pFormatCtx is an AvFormatContext and ioread is a function that fills your buffer from the receiver

For your second question i've also faced the same problems and unfortunately i didn't find a solution hope you find it and share it